# Gradle build executes test cases twice

Tags: gradle, junit, parameterized

Currently I am reading test cases from excel file and based on it program will prepare Collection for JUNIT parameterized test case. I have used Gradle as a build tool.

When I build using gradle it executes each test case twice. Currently I have 2 test cases in excel file and 1 in code. Ideally test result should be of 4 test cases. And it gives result as [image]

**Here is my test configuration in build.gradle file.**

[image]

**Find below the test configuration in code !**

[image]

**Please help to fix this problem !**

Comment: The line with `test.onlyIf`, which block is that part of? Looking at the braces it appears to be outside of anything you have put in the post. Can you provide the complete build.gradle file?

Comment: It is not a part of any block. It is gradle command like test .. Let say if you want to build your project by skipping test execution with command "gradle all -x test"